# Restangular Spinner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {        
    RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(function(element) {
        console.log("Request started");
        return element;
    });

    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data) {
        console.log("Request returned");

        return data;
   });
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a spinner for when a request is going on. I suspect that this is usually done by displaying a  when a request starts, and hiding it when the request is finished.

How can I do this with Angular and Restangular? I have the interceptors setup as above, but this is in the .conifg(), so I can't access the $rootScope or anything to keep track of the visibility of any div.

Comment: Check out this plugin: http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/ I haven't looked into how it works but he taps into pretty much every HTTP request and seems to handle it all pretty well. Works flawlessly with my Restangular setup.

Comment: I know of that plugin; I don't want to take the easy way out... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I can configure Restangular inside of the `run()` block, giving me access to the `$rootscope` like so:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, Restangular) {
    Restangular.addRequestInterceptor(function(element) {
        $rootScope.xhr = true;

        return element;
    });
    Restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function(data) {
        $rootScope.xhr = false;

        return data;
    });
});
```

Comment: This has a bug when loading several resources at the same time, you need to count the number of requests

Comment: @Blowsie just check if the spinner is already set to true dont count requests !

Comment: @ProllyGeek that doesn't make sense to me its set to true if you have 1 or 100 pending requests

Comment: @Blowsie im using the following exact scneario if loading is shown already, dont show it, and added a response interceptor to hide it, the unhandled scenario will be a request that is sent during another in pending state, however not all requests should be handled with loading, only ones that you really want user to stop interaction with your apps, for example not the load more scenario.